# Merge 2 images of the same size with GD

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I was viewing the php manual but unsuccessfully to make it work 1 transparent image on top another image `.jpg`

```
$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg'); 
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');

imagecopy($image1, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image1), imagesy($image1)); 

imagejpeg($image1, "ok.jpg");    

echo "<img src='ok.jpg' alt='test' >";
```

The two images have the same size the only difference and the second image is transparent and has a logo in a certain position

echo is only printing the first image

**EDIT**

**imagecopymerge**

```
 $image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg'); 
    $image2 = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');

    imagecopymerge($image1, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image1), imagesy($image1, 5)); 

    imagejpeg($image1, "ok.jpg");    

    echo "<img src='ok.jpg' alt='test' >";
```

**IMAGES**

watermarker.png
[image: watermarker.png]

image.jpg
[image: image.jpg]

ok.jpg - This should be the result, but only the T-shirt appears when it generates the file ok.jpg
[image: ok.jpg - This should be the result, but only the T-shirt appears when it generates the file ok.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

This function should be helpful to you http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

Comment: thanks, I already tried this function too, but it does not work, the second image does not appear on the first image

Comment: @Gislef You might want to show that code you tried, and the two images. Might be something as simple as you got the order wrong and put the JPG over the transparent PNG.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, my code is exactly the same as the question, just changing the name of the images

Comment: @Gislef I mean the `imagecopymerge` example.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, but the `imagecopymerge` only adds the transparency parameter at the end, I do not need this parameter because the image already has transparency, `imagecopymerge` would be like adding transparency to an image that is already transparent

Comment: @ceejayoz I edited my question, see how I tried with `imagecopymerge`

Comment: @Gislef Can you provide the two images you're working with?

Comment: @Gislef you use it this way imagecopymerge($image1, $image2...
did you try to do it like this? imagecopymerge($image2, $image1...

Comment: also (speaking about "imagecopymerge" example) remove last 2 lines with
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image1, "ok.jpg");

Comment: @evgpisarchik yes I tried this way by changing the positions of the images, and the strange thing is that the image appears the same way, nothing appears of the logo. Content-Type, whenever I try in this way everything appears black and in the center a small empty square with white lines

Comment: correcting myself: you should use imagepng($image1); (without "ok.jpg") after the header

Comment: @evgpisarchik I added the pictures in my question, please see

Comment: @Gislef I have time only tomorrow, if you find answer please post it under your question, otherwise I'll try to find it myself

Comment: @evgpisarchik I finally solved this, it was so simple, a mistake of mine, the two images were not the same size in pixel, the program I used to generate the image generated this in scala larger. Thank you for your attention and support.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reposition the logo/watermark.

You just have to get the coordinates (left and top) of four corners in the watermark.png and displace them to four coordinates of image.jpg:

```
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$watermark = new Imagick('watermark.png');
$controlPoints = [
    300,1700 /* watermark.png (left,top) coordinate moves to image.jpg (left,top) coordinate */ 800,900, // TOP LEFT CORNER
    1963,1700, /* to */ 1450,900, // TOP RIGHT CORNER
    1963,2500, /* to */ 1450,1100, // BOTTOM RIGHT CORNER
    300,2500, /* to */ 800,1100, // BOTTOM LEFT CORNER
];
$watermark->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $controlPoints, false);
$image->addImage($watermark);
$result = $image->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_MERGE);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($result->getImageBlob()) . '" alt="test" />';
```

You can play freely with the control points.

**But be careful** if you use images with different sizes because if one of the destination coordinates goes outside the size of the image to distort (the watermark) you must change to:

```
$watermark->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, true);
```

You have to change the first and the third arguments.

Comment: If you don't want to displace you just have to remove the $controlPoints variable and the $watermark->distortImage(...);